# Generating NACA airfoils with three digit maximal thickness numbers

Tags: airfoils

I have two wind turbine blades, one that that consists of NACA 44xx airfoils and the other NACA 63-2xx airfoils. Some sections of these blades have airfoils whose maximal thickness are specified by three digits, such as .247c (where 'c' is the chord length). Is there any program that will allow me to plot such an airfoil?

Comment: This : http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/naca4digit

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't let you enter a three digit thickness like 12.5%. EDIT: It does appear to make a difference entering 12.5% as opposed to 12%.

Comment: So run at 12 and 13 and interpolate...

Comment: Xfoil http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/